# Can I send Notification Center items to my iPhone using Pushover or Prowl?

Tags: iphone, applescript, notifications

The title pretty much sums it up. I often feel like having notifications on my iPhone are a lot easier to notice, especially if you step away from the computer for a few moments to do something and come back.

Ideally I would like an AppleScript or something similar that forwards my Notification Center items to my iPhone using [Pushover](https://pushover.net/) or [Prowl](http://www.prowlapp.com/) (ideally Pushover).

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

An extensive search has determined the following:

There are a number of ways to SEND notifications TO Notification Center in Mountain Lion.

There are currently no hook in AppleScript to read notifications FROM Notification Center. This would be a key starting point in piping such notifications to Pushover or Prowl.

Conclusion: As of OS X 10.8.2 - no. Sorry. :(

Good luck and happy notifying!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using EventScripts to do similar (Hazel triggers Applescript). See example here: http://www.mousedown.net/mouseware/Event_Scripting.html EventScripts is a cheap app that's available on the Mac App Store.

It doesn't need one of EventScripts 'events' just something to run the AppleScript and Tell EventScript to notify via PushOver.